# applicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification not called on iPhone 7 on background

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I want to set a local notification when a remote notification is received and app is in background. This works fine when I have my iPhone 7 device connected to xcode but once I disconnect the device and then put the app in background, local notification does not work and this is because applicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification is not being invoked (I tested it by setting a flag in UserDefaults in the same method which again was not being set). This same procedure when followed on iPhone 6 and 6s works completely fine both when connected and when not connected to xcode. The iOS version on iPhone 7 was 10.2.1 and then updated to 10.3.1 and it didn't work on both of the versions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got an answer from Apple. This point was the reason of the issue :

Silent push notifications (those whose payloads contain only the content-available key and no alert, badge, or sound keys) are throttled to be delivered only when iOS determines that it’s energy-efficient to do so. 
Push notifications with user-visible keys such as alert, sound, or badge sent at high priority (priority 10) are always displayed. **However, if the notification also contains the content-available key, the notification may be throttled and thus not be sent to the app in the background unless the user taps the notification.**

And the important point as the mail says is :
**The important point is that apps should never be designed expecting that every push notification will be received.**